# TD-IDF Find Cosine Similarity Between New Document and Dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I have a TF-IDF matrix of a dataset of products:

```
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer().fit_transform(words)
```

where **words** is a list of descriptions. This produces a 69258x22024 matrix.

Now I want to find *cosine similarities* between a new product and the ones in the matrix, as I need to find the 10 most similar products to it. I vectorize it using the same method above.

However, I cannot multiply the matrices because their sizes are different (the new one would be like 6 words, so a 1x6 matrix), so I need to make a TFIDFVectorizer with the number of columns as the original one.

How do I do it?

Comment: Can you clarify your question ? Is my answer sufficient ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have found a way for it to work. Instead of using fit_transform, you need to first fit the new document to the corpus TFIDF matrix like this:

```
queryTFIDF = TfidfVectorizer().fit(words)
```

Now we can 'transform' this vector into that matrix shape by using the *transform* function:

```
queryTFIDF = queryTFIDF.transform([query])
```

Where **query** is the query string.
We can then find cosine similarities and find the 10 most similar/relevant documents:

```
cosine_similarities = cosine_similarity(queryTFIDF, datasetTFIDF).flatten()
related_product_indices = cosine_similarities.argsort()[:-11:-1]
```

Comment: Good catch. I tested with a large corpora (1MM words) and the query time took less than 1.58s.

Comment: Does final list which is being passed to tfidfvectorizer contains only lemmatized words? Can we use custom preprocessing function  and then make list of lemmatized words as corpus and pass it in tfidfvectorizer, will it give me vector for each sentence?

Answer (score 5):

I think `words` variable is ambiguous. I advise you to rename `words` to `corpus`.

In fact you put all your documents in `corpus` variable first and after you compute your cosinus similarity.

Here an example :

**tf_idf.py:**

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

corpus = [
     'This is the first document.',
     'This is the second second document.',
     'And the third one.',
     'Is this the first document?',
]

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
words = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
similarity_matrix = cosine_similarity(tfidf)
```

Execute that in your `ipython` console :

```
In [1]: run tf_idf.py

In [2]: words
Out[2]: ['and', 'document', 'first', 'is', 'one', 'second', 'the', 'third', 'this']

In [3]: tfidf.toarray()
Out[3]: 
array([[ 0.        ,  0.43877674,  0.54197657,  0.43877674,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.35872874,  0.        ,  0.43877674],
       [ 0.        ,  0.27230147,  0.        ,  0.27230147,  0.        ,
         0.85322574,  0.22262429,  0.        ,  0.27230147],
       [ 0.55280532,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.55280532,
         0.        ,  0.28847675,  0.55280532,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.43877674,  0.54197657,  0.43877674,  0.        ,
         0.        ,  0.35872874,  0.        ,  0.43877674]])

In [4]: similarity_matrix
Out[4]: 
array([[ 1.        ,  0.43830038,  0.1034849 ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.43830038,  1.        ,  0.06422193,  0.43830038],
       [ 0.1034849 ,  0.06422193,  1.        ,  0.1034849 ],
       [ 1.        ,  0.43830038,  0.1034849 ,  1.        ]])
```

Note :

- `tfidf` is a `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix`, `to_array` convert to a `numpy.ndarray` (but is is costly, just here to see easily the content).
- similarity_matrix is a symetric matrix.

You can do:

```
import numpy as np
print(np.triu(similarity_matrix, k=1))
```

Give :

```
array([[ 0.        ,  0.43830038,  0.1034849 ,  1.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.06422193,  0.43830038],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.1034849 ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]])
```

To see only interesting similarities.

See :

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#text-feature-extraction

Comment: Thanks, but I want to do it without adding the new query/document to the dataset.

Comment: I want to point out that this approach is incorrect, since this gives you train/test bleed if you'd apply it to a real task, because you fit the tf-idf vectorizer on the test data. The accepted answer is correct in that it only calls transform on the test data.