# Cosine Similarity between 2 cells in a datafame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, data-science

```py
doc_1 = data.iloc[15]['Description']
doc_2 = "Data is a new oil"

data = [doc_1, doc_2]

count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
vector_matrix = count_vectorizer.fit_transform(data)

tokens = count_vectorizer.get_feature_names()
vector_matrix.toarray()

def create_dataframe(matrix, tokens):

    doc_names = [f'doc_{i+1}' for i, _ in enumerate(matrix)]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=matrix, index=doc_names, columns=tokens)
    return(df)

create_dataframe(vector_matrix.toarray(),tokens)

cosine_similarity_matrix = cosine_similarity(vector_matrix)
create_dataframe(cosine_similarity_matrix,['doc_1','doc_2'])
```

The code calculate the  Cosine Similarity between a cell and the string, but how can i improve my code so that i can calculate the Cosine Similarity between cells. So i want `doc1` compared with all the other cells in the column.

So i will get a table like this, where the dots is de cosine similarities:

| x | doc2 | doc3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| doc1 | .... | .... |

picture of the table how it should look like
[image]

Comment: Does [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44863365/1409374) help?

Comment: no not really. I want to compare one cell with all the other cell of the same column

Comment: What is `doc_1`?  Is it just a single sentence like `doc_2`?

Comment: no supposed to be a cell/value

Comment: I meant here, `doc_1 = data.iloc[15]['Description']`.

Comment: both need to be a cell/value, like doc_1 is already a cell/value

Comment: Would you show an example of "cell/value"?